# How can I resolve this promise from external function in React JSX?

Tags: async-await, promise, jsx

I need some help understanding what and why this does not work when in React JSX, but does in standard JS.

First off, what is it called when you reference a var as a function?

```
var promiseResolve;
promiseResolve();
```

And second why does React return: "Uncaught TypeError: promiseResolve is not a function" when trying to call it?

I know this sounds like a intro question, but I've been doing pretty complex JS and now React web builds for five years now, and I embarrassingly don't know what it means to call an undefined function like that.

This all fits into a bigger question of trying to resolve a promise from an await in an external function via a modal, but without trying to go into detail, if the below would work in JSX, it would solve my problems.

```
var promiseResolve, promiseReject;

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  promiseResolve = resolve;
  promiseReject = reject;
});

promiseResolve();
```

For more context, I'm trying to get this to work (EDIT: request to show full code after this blurb. Everything else works, it's only recently I was asked to add a process to warn if an email was already sent):

```
let promiseResolve, promiseReject;
  const resendAttempt = () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    promiseResolve = resolve;
    promiseReject = reject;
  });
  const resolvePromise = () => {
    promiseResolve();
  }

return (

  <Modal... <button onclick={resolvePromise} ... /> ... />

    <Form onSubmit={async (values ...

    await resendAttempt();

)}
/>
)
```

FULL CODE, look for comments on where issue is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, useField, FieldArray, Field } from 'formik';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Button from 'components/Elements/Button';
import H3 from 'components/Elements/H2';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import BootstrapButton from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Wrapper from './Wrapper';

const TeamRecruitmentForm = props => {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(true);
  const [customFormError, setCustomFormError] = useState(false);
  const [customFormSuccess, setCustomFormSuccess] = useState(false);

  const [recruitRow, setRecruitRow] = useState({
    recruitFirstName: '',
    recruitLastName: '',
    recruitEmail: ''
  });

  const captFirstName = props.userData.name ? props.userData.name.first : '';
  const captLastName = props.userData.name ? props.userData.name.last : '';
  const cityName = props.customGreetingFields.eventCity ? props.customGreetingFields.eventCity : '';

  let messageSubject = `Join ${captFirstName} ${captLastName}\'s Leaders for Life Team`;
  
  let promiseResolve, promiseReject;
  const resendAttempt = () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    promiseResolve = resolve;
    promiseReject = reject;
  });
  // this is called with a modaal button click
  const resolvePromise = () => {
    promiseResolve(); // JS errror, console says it is not a function
  }
  
  const [showTeammember, setShowTeammember] = useState(false);
  const [showResend, setShowResend] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log('handleClose');
    setShowTeammember(false);
    setShowResend(false);
  };
  const handleShow = (modal) => {
    console.log('handleShow');
    if (modal == 'teammember') {
      setShowTeammember(true);
    } else if (modal == 'resend') {
      setShowResend(true);
    }
  };

  function validateEmail(value,x) {
    let error;
    const filterTeamRoster = props.teamRosterActivity.filter(user => {
      return user.email == value;
    });

    if (!value) {
      error = 'Required';
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value)) {
      error = 'Invalid email address';
    }
    else if (filterTeamRoster.length > 0) {
      handleShow('teammember');
      error = 'Current Teammember';
    }
    return error;
  }

  function validateFirstName(value) {
    let error;
    if (!value) {
      error = 'Required';
    }
    return error;
  }

  function validateLastName(value) {
    let error;
    if (!value) {
      error = 'Required';
    }
    return error;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        show={showTeammember}
        id={props.id}
        size={props.size}
        onHide={handleClose}
        className={`mx-auto ${props.modalClass}`}
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton closeLabel="Back" className="bg-primary py-1">
          <BootstrapButton
            variant="link"
            onClick={handleClose}
            className={`text-white btn-modal-back btn-back-${props.modalClass}`}
          >
            <span className="fas fa-caret-left" alt="" />
            &nbsp;Back
          </BootstrapButton>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
        <H3>Current Teammember</H3>
        <p>The person associated with the email address has already joined your team</p>

        <Button variant="primary" className="btn-block" onClick={handleClose}>
          OK
        </Button>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>

      <Modal
        show={showResend}
        id={props.id}
        size={props.size}
        onHide={handleClose}
        className={`mx-auto ${props.modalClass}`}
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton closeLabel="Back" className="bg-primary py-1">
          <BootstrapButton
            variant="link"
            onClick={handleClose}
            className={`text-white btn-modal-back btn-back-${props.modalClass}`}
          >
            <span className="fas fa-caret-left" alt="" />
            &nbsp;Back
          </BootstrapButton>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
        <H3>You already sent an invite to this email address.</H3>
        <p>Would you like to send it again"</p>

  
        {/* This is the button I'm using to test allowing the dupe email
        form to be send */}
        <Button variant="primary" className="btn-block" onClick={resolvePromise}>
          OK
        </Button>

        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>

      <Wrapper key={props.formNumber} {...props}>
              {customFormError === false && customFormSuccess === true ? (
                  <div className="my-1">
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={6} md={3}
                                  className="pr-1 pr-md-2 pb-2 email-sent-container"><span className="email-sent">{recruitRow.recruitFirstName}</span></Col>
                      <Col xs={6} md={3}
                                  className="pr-1 pr-md-2 pb-2 email-sent-container"><span className="email-sent">{recruitRow.recruitLastName}</span></Col>
                      <Col md={4}
                                  className="pl-md-2 pb-2 email-sent-container"><span className="email-sent">{recruitRow.recruitEmail}</span></Col>
                      <Col xs={6} md={2}
                                  className="pb-2">
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" disabled>
                          Sent!
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                ) :
                (<Formik
                {...props}
                initialValues={{ recruits: [{firstName: "", lastName: "", emailAddress: ""}] }}
                validateOnChange={false}
                validateOnBlur={false}

                onSubmit={ async (values, { setSubmitting, setFieldError, setStatus }) => {


                  // this is the array it checks in order to kick bcak option to continue
                  // or cancel the submissions process
                  const filterSentMessages = props.sentMessages.filter(user => {
                    return user.recipients == values['emailAddress'+props.formNumber];
                  });
                  console.log("before sleep");
                  if (filterSentMessages.length > 0) {
                    handleShow('resend');
                  }
                  // this works, but the button click in the modal
                  // to resolve this is the issue where I get undefined
                  await resendAttempt();



                  let recipient = `${values['firstName'+props.formNumber]} ${values['lastName'+props.formNumber]} <${encodeURIComponent(values['emailAddress'+props.formNumber])}>,`;
                  console.info('recipient:', recipient);
                  let messageBody = `<p>Dear ${values['firstName'+props.formNumber]},</p><p>... message content ...</p><p>Thank you in advance for your commitment to making an impact!</p><p>${captFirstName}!</p>`
                  messageBody = encodeURIComponent(messageBody);

                  let x = 2; // this is here to just stop sending so many test emails
                  if( x == 1 ) { // this is here to just stop sending so many test emails
                  try {
                    props.sendMessage(
                      localStorage.getItem('frId'),
                      messageSubject,
                      messageBody,
                      recipient,
                      props.eventConfig.defaultStationeryId,
                    );
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log('form submit error:', error);
                    setShowForm(!showForm);
                    setSubmitting(false);
                  }
                  }
                  setRecruitRow({...recruitRow, recruitFirstName: values['firstName'+props.formNumber], recruitLastName: values['lastName'+props.formNumber], recruitEmail: values['emailAddress'+props.formNumber]})
                  setCustomFormError(false);
                  setCustomFormSuccess(true);
                  setSubmitting(false);

                }}
                render={({ values,errors }) => (

                  <Form className="my-1" id={`recruitForm${props.formNumber}`}>
                    <FieldArray
                      name="recruits"
                      render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                        <>
                          {(values.recruits && values.recruits.length > 0) && (
                            values.recruits.map((recruit, index) => (
                              <Row key={props.formNumber}>
                                <Col xs={6} md={3}
                                  className="pr-1 pr-md-2 pb-2"
                                >
                                  <label htmlFor={`firstName${props.formNumber}`} className="sr-only">
                                    First Name
                                  </label>
                                  <Field
                                    className="form-control"
                                    type="text"
                                    name={`firstName${props.formNumber}`}
                                    placeholder="First Name"
                                    id={`firstName${props.formNumber}`}
                                    validate={validateFirstName}
                                  />
                                  {errors['firstName'+props.formNumber] && <div className="text-danger" role="alert">{errors['firstName'+props.formNumber]}</div>}
                                </Col>
                                <Col xs={6} md={3}
                                  className="pl-1 px-md-2 pb-2"
                                >
                                  <label htmlFor={`lastName${props.formNumber}`} className="sr-only">
                                    Last Name
                                  </label>
                                  <Field
                                    className="form-control"
                                    type="text"
                                    name={`lastName${props.formNumber}`}
                                    placeholder="Last Name"
                                    id={`lastName${props.formNumber}`}
                                    validate={validateLastName}
                                  />
                                  {errors['lastName'+props.formNumber] && <div className="text-danger" role="alert">{errors['lastName'+props.formNumber]}</div>}
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={4}
                                  className="pl-md-2 pb-2"
                                >
                                  <label htmlFor={`emailAddress${props.formNumber}`} className="sr-only">
                                    Email Address
                                  </label>
                                  <Field
                                    className="form-control"
                                    type="text"
                                    name={`emailAddress${props.formNumber}`}
                                    placeholder="Email Address"
                                    id={`emailAddress${props.formNumber}`}
                                    validate={validateEmail}
                                  />
                                  {errors['emailAddress'+props.formNumber] && <div className="text-danger" role="alert">{errors['emailAddress'+props.formNumber]}</div>}
                                </Col>
                                <Col xs={6} md={2}
                                  className="pb-2"
                                >
                                  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                    Send
                                  </Button>
                                </Col>
                              </Row>

                            ))
                          )}
                        </>
                      )}
                    />
                  </Form>
                )}
          />
          )}
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default TeamRecruitmentForm;
```

Comment: Your code is broken, but I think your example should in theory not throw that error. Try to share an example that actually accurately reproduces the issue... hard to tell with what you gave us since it's not valid code.

Comment: Thanks @Evert, I have posted the full code as an edit. That short piece was just to try and make it easier to follow. I'm still curious what calling a var as a function is called too. Thank you.